# Notification window with buttons in Linux

Tags: perl, notifications, xorg

I have a Perl script which listens to a port and filters messages, and, based on them, proposes to take action or ignore event.

I'd like to make it show a notification window (not a dialogue window) with buttons 'take action' and 'ignore', which would go after a certain timeout.

So far I have something like this:

```
my @react = ("somecommand", "someoptions); # based on what regex a message matched

my $cmd = "xmessage";
my $cmd_args = "-print -timeout 7 -buttons React,Dismiss $message"; # raw message from port

open XMSG, "$cmd $cmd_args |";
while (<XMSG>) {
    if ($_ eq "React\n") {
         do something...
    }
}
```

But it would handle only one notification at once, and the next message would not appear until the previous one is dismissed, reacted to or timed out, so it's quite a bad decision. I cannot do anything until I get return code from xmessage, and I can't get xmessage run a command. Well I probably can if I introduce event IDs and listen to a socket where xmessage prints, but it would make things too complicated, I guess.

So I wonder is there a library or an utility for Linux to draw notify-like windows with buttons which would each trigger a command?

Comment: You could fork, or call a different script to control the window.

Comment: Yep. But I'd like to pass all of the interaction to the window too. I.e. script calls `mywindowlib -buttons foo -command $bar -timeout 3` and works further. The problem is, what's `mywindowlib`.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~kck/UI-Dialog/lib/UI/Dialog.pod Might work.

Comment: That's a uniform interface to existing dialog tools, which is not necessary and probably doesn't solve the problem. Anyway, I've written a Tk porgram which works just the way I want, I wonder if I should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I didn't see this one when it first was posted. There are several gui toolkits which could do something along these lines. [Prima](http://metacpan.org/module/Prima) is a toolkit built especially for Perl and has no external library dependencies.

For when you just need a popup dialog, there is the [Ask](https://metacpan.org/module/Ask) module which delegates the task of popping up windows to any available library.

Comment: It's a nice library I haven't heard of before. Not sure if there's a way to set window type there like in Tk.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone's interested, I've ended up writing a small Tcl/Tk program for that, the full code (all 48 lines) can be found here: http://cloudcabin.org/read/twobutton_notify, and you can ignore the text in Russian around it.